# Whats wrong with this GUI program? - it says 'tra' is not defined

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

im a beginner programer and made this GUI ceasar code encrypter. I based it on a normal python program i made earlier, and i think i changed sufficiently, but evidently i didnt as it doesnt work. It tells me that the variable 'tra' is not defined.
The program:

```
from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
    super(Application, self).__init__(master)
    self.grid()
    self.createwidgets()

def createwidgets(self):
    Label(self,
          text = "Encrypt a message:",
          ).grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)

    Label(self,
          text = "Whats your message?:",
          ).grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)
    self.messageent = Entry(self)
    self.messageent.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = W)

    Label(self,
          text = "Whats the key?:(1 - 25)",
          ).grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = W)
    self.keyent = Entry(self)
    self.keyent.grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky = W)
    
    Button(self,
           text = "Click for coded message",
           command = self.encrypt
           ).grid(row = 6, column = 0, sticky = W)

    self.messagetxt = Text(self, width = 75, height = 10, wrap = WORD)
    self.messagetxt.grid(row = 7, column = 0, columnspan = 4)

def things():
    message = self.messageent.get()
    key = self.keyent.get()

def getTranslatedMessage(message, key):

    tra = ''
    
    for symbol in message:
        if symbol.isalpha():
            num = ord(symbol)
            num += key

            if symbol.isupper():
                if num > ord('Z'):
                    num -= 26
                elif num < ord('A'):
                    num += 26
            elif symbol.islower():
                if num > ord('z'):
                    num -= 26
                elif num < ord('a'):
                    num += 26

        
            tra += chr(num)
        else:
            tra += symbol

def encrypt(self):
    encryptedmessage = tra

    self.messagetxt.delete(0.0, END)
    self.messagetxt.insert(0.0, encryptedmessage)

root = Tk()
root.title("Encrypting message")
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

please could tell me whats wrong in this program and how to fix it?
By the way, i am only 12, and i am actually doing programming as a hobby. So i am planning to get better -  i made a version of this code in normal(not GUI) python on my own and it worked - want to challenge myself and try to make it work in GUI.

Thank you

Comment: your declaring `global tra` in your `getTranslatedMessage` this tells the function to consider all references to tra in your function to refer to the global instance of `tra` but you dont have tra defined globally. Just remove this line

Comment: Fix the indentation of your code first.

Answer (score -2):

I copy/pasted your code and tried to compile it. That resulted in a large number of errors -- even after fixing the initial indentation errors. The main problem is that the variable `tra` is defined in function `getTranslatedMessage()` but you try to use it in `encrypt()`. It seems like you intended for both of those functions to be methods of the `Application` class; or something similar. Providing a good answer is difficult because your question has a large number of problems.